# How to show that Language is not Context Free?

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

There is a question to show that $L=\{a^{n!} \mid n \geq 0 \}$ is not regular using Pumping Lemma. However, I have the answer in the book which is found to be somewhere wrong. I am sharing the snapshot of the answer which I could not figure out. Could anybody correct it so that the puzzle could be solved?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a [pumping lemma for context free languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages) too.

In you case, if $L$ was context free, then there would be some constant $n_0$ such that all words $a^{n!}$ with $n! \ge n_0$, $a^{n!}$ could be decomposed as:
$$
a^{n!} = a^x a^y  a^v a^w a^z 
$$
such that $y+v+w \le n_0$, $y+v \ge 1$, and for all $i \ge 0$:
$$
a^x a^{yi}  a^v a^{wi} a^z \in L.
$$

Calling $\ell = y+w$ and simplifying, the above can be rewritten as:
$
a^{n!} = a^\ell a^{n! - \ell}
$
such that, for all $i \ge 0$, $a^{n!+(i-1)\ell} \in L$.

This cannot be true. To see this pick, e.g., $n=n_0+2$, and $i=0$.
Then $a^{n!+(i-1)\ell} = a^{(n_0+2)!-\ell}$, where
$
(n_0+2)! - \ell \le (n_0+2)! - 1 < (n_0+2)!
$
and
$
(n_0+2)! - \ell \ge (n_0+2)! - n_0 = (n_0+1) \cdot (n_0+1)! - n_0 > (n_0+1)!
$, showing that $n!-\ell \in ((n_0+1)!, (n_0+2)!)$ and hence it cannot be expressed as a factorial.

Answer (score 0):

A unary language $L$ is context-free iff it is regular iff it is eventually periodic, that is, if the set $N = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : a^n \in L\}$ satisfies the following property: there exist $m \geq 0$ and $r \geq 1$ such that for all $n \geq m$ we have $n \in N$ iff $n + r \in N$.

In particular, any unary language which has zero limiting density (i.e., $\min_{n\to\infty} |N \cap \{1,\ldots,n\}/n = 0$) must be finite. Your language has zero limiting density, yet is infinite.